# Suggestion on preamp, RME QuadMic 4 channel preamp?

Tags: preamp, fostex, sound-devices, recording

I'm looking for a 2 channel, preferably 4 channel, mic preamp for the studio. My budget is around €350, which is what the RME QuadMic is going for in Europe. It seems to suite my needs but I'm not fully convinced about the quality of the pres. The people at gearslutz seem to have mixed opinions about RME's amps and their opinion mostly is based on vocal and instrument recording. I will mainly be using the amp for foley/sfx recording in the studio.

I was wondering how the QuadMic amps compare to the FR2 which I have or the Sound Devices stuff, which is above my budget. Do any of you guys have experience with the QuadMic or other RME amps? Suggestions for other 2 or 4 channel amps are most welcome. I'd gladly buy SD stuff, but in my current situation I just can't justify spending that kind of money on this hobby.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: I really doubt there's anything significantly different in the pres, at least in this price category and until you actually verify it yourself. Even RME can be viewed as and actually is technically very high-end equipment. I think RME stuff is faultless and inside the bounds of still being fairly rational (as opposed to obsessive "high-end purism" oh so common in e.g. Gearslutz).

Comment: What comes to SD pres, this Tascam has better quality amplification: https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-art-tech-gallery/pages/Emil_DR680_SD702_QuadMic_Compare-present.html . Just food for thought.

Comment: The "high-end purism" is the reason I take the info on GS with a grain of salt. I figured I might get better opinions on here. Thanks for your comment regarding RME. Thanks for the SD/Tascam comparison aswell.